# Why is my .x3d export from Paraview not complete (in Client/Server)?

Tags: paraview, x3d

I am trying to export a scene from Paraview so that I can work on it in blender. Following instructions found on multiple sources on internet (example [here](https://www.slideshare.net/JuliendeCharentenay/o-f-rendering-using-blender), slide 9), one of the ways of doing this is by exporting a Paraview scene with the .x3d format.
So, I try to do just that.
In Paraview, I have some pathlines, with tubes around it, colored by velocity. I **show** these in Paraview, even **select** them in the tree, like this

[image]

Then File > Export Scene... > X3D Files.

After this, when I check the produced x3d file, there is no 3D data in it, as illustrated below (vi on the x3d file):

[image]

So.. what am I doing wrong here? I use Paraview 5.4.1.

Thanks a lot for any help!

**Edit:** I am trying to do this in client/server mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution, hopefully this can help others.

In Paraview, go in Edit > Settings... > Render View
Then set the Remote Render Threshold to the max, as illustrated below.

[image]

PS: I found the solution [here](https://www.paraview.org/pipermail/paraview/2016-September/038104.html).

Comment: I opened an issue : https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview/issues/19715